# C++ code coverage tool running on command line

Tags: c++, code-coverage

I use code coverage tool for writing unit testing cases. I have a code coverage tool but only have to do everything through its GUI interface. Ideally I'd like to get a tool that is able to produce a text output (.diff is the best) on individual .cpp files. Does such a tool exist?

Answer (score 4):

[gcov](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html) can and does produce text output. Make sure you use a recent gcc to get coverage of shared libraries.

I'm not sure how you can have diff output of coverage though?

Comment: If you combine gcov with lcov, you can create some excellent graphical views of the results in HTML.