# is it possible to redefine { and } in C?

Tags: c

Is there any way you do something like...

```
#define {  { printf("%s,%s",_FUNCTION_, _LINE_); {
```

this won't compile.   But I'm wondering if there is some kind of trick to effectively get the same functionality?  (other than writing a tool to hook at the preprocessing step)

The point of doing this is a pondering on how to get a poor mans code coverage.

Comment: A poor man's Aspect Oriented Programming in c? Good luck with that.

Comment: yes....perhaps I should of explained a bit more .... will edit

Comment: what if { // this happens } ?

Comment: I feel a really bad macro attack coming on here.

Comment: @Matt,   shouldn't make any difference

Comment: @Matt:  Comments are removed from the source and replaced with whitespace before preprocessing directives and macro invocations are evaluated.

Comment: It's not going to play very nicely with `struct` definitions, or compound initialisers...

Comment: I would suggest a Perl script that functions as a prepreprocessor.

Comment: @caf, I know, which is problematic, but in *my* specific case it wouldn't be too hard to work around

Comment: If Steven Rostedt could redefine `if`... http://lwn.net/Articles/308520/

Comment: @Keith Nicholas, @James McNellis, I meant an IF statement. Even if you could do this you'd be printing traces any time there are brackets, such as ifs, loops etc. I suppose if you WANT that...

Comment: @Keith Ah, yeah that makes sense. I saw _FUNCTION_ and assumed it was a function trace, not noticing _LINE_

Comment: I've given it up :)   I think my own preprocessor is the way to go.

only problem is, thats going to take a fair bit longer to implement, so it I'll just whack it on the "todo sometime" list

Comment: @Keith: use a lexer-generator like flex, and modify the lexer grammar from http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l.html. You should be looking for something pretty simple, like have every token print its exact text, except for open brackets, which would print back some expansion.

Answer (score 7):

It's certainly not possible with a macro.  The name of a macro must be an identifier.  The brace characters are punctuators, not identifiers.

Comment: sorry, edited the question,  I know its not possible with macros as is.... was looking to see if there's a trick, or even a non standard compiler trick

Comment: @Keith:  A trick to change the way brace punctuators are handled?  I doubt it; that's a rather unusual "feature request" :-).

Comment: I know..... I know....  but how cool would that be :-)   It's C after all, give me the power to Nuke myself in the head :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this done (not that I endorse it...) with `#define BEGIN ...` and `#define END ...`.

e.g.

```
void foo(void)
BEGIN
    stuff();
END
```

Comment: really don't want that,  would like to be able to adhoc change the {  and } to something else,  as someone said,  poor mans AOP to get poor mans code coverage

Answer (score 1):

Get rich-man's code coverage with the tools discussed in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459287/c-code-coverage-tool-running-on-command-line) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458186/open-source-c-code-coverage-tool-with-gui), particularly [gcov](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html), which is part of GCC.

Comment: yes, I realize I could use a rich tool,  but I was also going to inject debug code for an embedded system so you could trace what its doing.  Sort of a real time coverage system....

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the way the compiler interprets {}'s. It's an assumption that they make to be able to syntaxically determine if the code is correct and what it is supposed to do.

If you indeed would like to do something like that, I suggest doing a search-and-replace on "{" "{ MY_MACRO;"

Answer (score 0):

Not with standard macros, no. The C standard (C11) has a specific requirement for macros in `6.10.3 Macro replacement`:

```
# define identifier replacement-list new-line
```

with `identifier` being explicitly defined in `6.4.2.1 Identifiers, General` as:

```
identifier:
    identifier-nondigit
    identifier identifier-nondigit
    identifier digit
identifier-nondigit:
    nondigit
    universal-character-name
    other implementation-defined characters
nondigit: one of
    _ a b c d e f g h i j k l m
    n o p q r s t u v w x y z
    A B C D E F G H I J K L M
    N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
digit: one of
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

So the only *possible loophole would be `other implementation-defined characters` but that's not covered by the standard, hence not really portable.

In any case, it wouldn't work very well with code like:

```
typedef struct {
    int field1;
    int field2;
} tMyStruct;
```

since it would rather annoyingly place a C statement where no statements should ever exist :-)

I think if you really want to do this, you're going to have pre-process your file with a more intelligent pre-processor (one that can tell where and where not the code should go), or modify the code to explicitly put in a macro where they should be, such as selecting behaviour with:

```
#ifdef PING_DEBUGGING
    #define MYPING printf("%s,%s", _FUNCTION_, _LINE_)
#else
    #define MY_PING
#endif
```

and  using it with:

```
void myFunc(void) { MYPING;
    // proper body of function.
}
```